# Moving site columns and content types between farms

Tags: content-type, site-column

I can't seem to find the codeplex solution that helps export site columns, content types and import back to another sc or farm.

Idea is to retain the guid for these. I know create wsp vs project is the way to go but I am the only developer and dont have time create projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found these two PowerShell posts from Phil Childs quite helpful in my attempts (I presume you are looking for a PowerShell approach) -

- [Export and import/create site columns in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html)
- [Export and import/create site content types in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/export-and-importcreate-site-content.html)